# Conjugate of I \[Phi]

Tags: complex

I have a bigger expression of which I have to take the conjugate.
But this is in itself perplexing.
When I write

> `ComplexExpand[Conjugate[Iϕ]]`

I just get back

> $I\phi$

I don't get how this returns the expression without changing the sign.

Comment: You should have a space between `I` and `ϕ`, otherwise it is treated as just a single symbol.

Comment: @Sektor It doesn't make sense to fix the problem in the question itself so I rolled back your edit.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I edited the question first and then tried to fix in a session, so just did everything backwards :D

Comment: @Sektor I understand, and thank you for your edits; this case was an unusual exception.

Comment: @Sektor : Adding the space does the trick! And also solves a lot of other problems I was having. Did not know it was being treated as a single symbol. Thank you! :-)

Answer (score 3):

You might find useful the following rule:

```
rule={Complex[0, 1] -> -I, Complex[0, -1] -> I};
```

For example, let us look at the following mildly complex expression:

```
expr = (a + b*I + Sqrt[c - d*I])/(a - b*I + Sqrt[c + d*I])^(3/2);
```

One finds the instance

```
 expr /. {a -> 1, b -> 1, c -> 1, d -> 1} // N

(*    0.546701 + 0.402882 I     *)
```

After application of the rule

```
expr /. rule

(*  (a - I b + Sqrt[c + I d])/(a + I b + Sqrt[c - I d])^(3/2)  *)
```

and at the same values of the parameters one gets:

```
    expr /. rule /. {a -> 1, b -> 1, c -> 1, d -> 1} // N

(*   0.546701 - 0.402882 I  *)
```

Have fun!